# How to restore user account from different boot?

Tags: macos, login, login-screen

So I did something dumb and now I'm locked out of my Mavericks partition on my MacBook. The dumb thing I did, specifically, was trying to change the user folder using the Directory Utility app, which should have worked but it didn't for some reason, and now I can't log in. Still have a Yosemite partition on the same computer though.

What I want to know is, is there a way, from outside the Mavericks boot, to change the home folder info? I know this info must be in some config file somewhere, however deeply hidden. Failing that, can I create a guest account, or enable root user, or any of that magic from outside the boot?

Oh, and please don't take this opportunity to lecture me about backup drives. The one I was using failed and I'm a student who can't afford another one right now. Life is hard.

Answer (score 1):

Boot to your Recovery HD or the Yosemite volume. Then open from the menubar Utilities -> Terminal (Recovery HD) or Go To -> Utilities -> Terminal (Yosemite)

- Enter `cd /Volumes/name_of_your_Mavericks_volume/private/var/db`.
- List the content of the folder with `ls -laO`. A file with the name *.AppleSetupDone* should be listed amongst other files and folders.
- Then enter `rm .AppleSetupDone` booted to Recovery HD (or `sudo rm .AppleSetupDone` booted to Yosemite) and then `exit`.

After rebooting to your Mavericks volume you will be asked to configure your OS X. Create a new temporary admin user. Log-in with the temporary admin user and repair your main admin user with *Directory Utility*.

Comment: That sounds like that's gonna work. I'll give it a try as soon as I can and let you know. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yup, that did it. Clever trick!